# How to mix two image using clipping in css?

Tags: css, image-clipping

I have two images link.

Original image -

[image]

Masking image -

[image]

Here is the result image.

[image]

How can i get the result like this?

I was finding some way using css - `clip-path : rect(....)` but I can't find 
using image mask.

Comment: You just want to use clipping? How about following an easier CSS approach to enclose the image in a container of circular shape? `border-radius: 50% and overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thanks your advice. But there is many other shape. So I'll find another way to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the mask is a .png, where the grey part is transparent. Then, use it in the following way:

CSS: `img{background-image: url('original_image');}`

HTML: `<img src="mask.png"/>`

See an example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjOwpe

You might want to use some of the CSS background properties to align the original image in such a way that the correct part of it is shown (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)